# Click CommandButton with win32com

Tags: python, excel, windows, win32com

I have a Form with a CommandButton in my excel sheet and I would like to click it with my python script.

Things that do NOT work:

```
import win32com.client

xl = win32com.client.Dispatch('Excel.Application')
xl.Workbooks.Open(file)
xl.Application.Run('CommandButton.1')
```

I am guessing this does not work as it is not a macro

```
import win32com.client

xl = win32com.client.Dispatch('Excel.Application')
xl.Workbooks.Open(file)
xl.DoCmd.OpenForms('CommandButton.1')
xl.Forms('CommandButton.1').CommandButton_Click()
```

This did not work because DoCmd is for Access and does not apply to Excel.

Comment: Suggestion: move the functionality of the command button into a separate subroutine and then have the click handler call it. Then I would think approach 1 should work if you change `'CommandButton.1'` to that separate subroutine.

Comment: I thought of that, but it created a new problem as there are other functionalities linked (a few checkboxes for options)